# How to create loop of posts except post ID defined via ACF field

Tags: posts, wp-query, query-posts

I am creating a custom news page with two columns -

1st column - featured post - using a ACF text field to add post ID to show, ie: 12345 - works fine.
2nd column - remaining news, showing all other news. works fine.

**Question is - how do i exclude the featured post (ACF FIELD) in column 1, being shown in newsfeed on column 2.**

Thank you,

J

Comment: let's Show your code

Comment: or if there is another way to do this, please let me know - thanks!

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

post__not_in (array) – use post ids. Specify post NOT to retrieve.

Comment: Yes if you don't provide any code examples it's hard for us to help as we guess.  Always provide code snippets when possible, otherwise you won't really get any responses.